# How to dsiplay value from another model based on the same if form another model in django

Tags: sql, django

I have db and the following classes:

in `models.py`

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Class101(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    math=models.DecimalField(max_length=200)
    english=models.DecimalField(max_length=200)
```

in `views.py`

```
total_grade=Class101.objects.filter(Q(math__gt=70) & Q(english__gt=58))

context ={'tg':total_grade}
```

in `template.html`

```
{% for grade in tg %}

 <p> {{grade.name}} </p>  

{% endfor %}
```

it lists name of students however i want to put in the template :

```
{{grade.name}} - {{grade.surname}}
```

`{{grade.surname}}` where surname is from model Student

This code does not display surname but only name as the name in the class Class101 . How to make to display surname from another model where both models have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you should have [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) relation between `Class101` and `Student` model like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Class(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    math=models.DecimalField(max_length=200)
    english=models.DecimalField(max_length=200)
```

Then you could use `Student` value in template:

```
{% for grade in tg %}

 <p> {{grade.student.name}} - {{grade.student.surename}} </p>  

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why student ? your code does not work as there is no column student in table Class101

Comment: i get an error  : "Unknown column " operation error

Comment: you need to run makemigrations and migrate to make this code work

Comment: still not shpowing anything

Comment: i do want to amemake changes to db any way to replace this method ? as my other codes use name since there are classes 102,103,104,105 and so on.

Comment: In that case, you should only have one model, and add a field code to distinguish classes between `102` `103` etc. Please see the updated answer